# i think something's wrong with my switch case

Tags: c++, struct

I'm reading in strings from a txt file and then matching it with a list of keywords (bubby, bonny, computer) via a switch case, and then initialize a struct. but i'm getting the following error.

```
+        _struct    0x00efb7b0 {g=<Error reading characters of string.> HL=-431602080. mg_i=-431602080. ...}    D *
```

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



struct D
{
    string g;
    float HL, mg_i, mg_m, t;
    float tau = HL / abs(log(0.5));
};




void scan(string, int&);


ifstream rlog;
ofstream wlog;
string line;
int main()
{
    int ptr;
    string month[] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
    //time_t t_i, t_f = time(0);
    //tm *ltm = localtime(&t_f);

    rlog.open("log.txt");
    scan(" :", ptr);


    string _list[3] = {"bubby", "bonny", "computer"};
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if (line.find(_list[i]) < line.length()){
            j++;
        }
    }

    D *_struct = (D*)malloc(j*sizeof(D));

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
        if (line.find(_list[i]) < line.length()){
            switch (i){
            case '1':
                (_struct + i)->g = "bubby";
                _struct[i].HL = 9.0;
                _struct[i].mg_m = 150;
                break;
            case '2':
                (_struct + i)->g = "bonny";
                _struct[i].HL = 8.5;
                _struct[i].mg_m = 450;
                break;
            case '3':
                (_struct + i)->g = "computer";
                _struct[i].HL = 48.755;
                _struct[i].mg_m = 360;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    return 0;
}


void scan(string s, int &i)
{
    while (!rlog.eof()){
        getline(rlog, line);        //READ IN
        if (line.find(s) > line.length()){}
        else{
            i = line.find(s);
            break;
        }                //EXIT FUNCT WEN FOUND
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `case '1':` -> `case 1:`, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You have a serious problem with this:

```
D *_struct = (D*)malloc(j*sizeof(D));
```

The `malloc` function only allocate memory, it doesn't call the constructors of structures and classes, which means that the `std::string` member `D::g` will not be constructed properly.

In C++ you should almost never use `malloc` directly, when you want to allocate memory dynamically you should use `new`, or when allocating an array `new[]`:

```
D* _struct = new D[j];
```

An even better solution would be using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<D> _struct(j);
```

---

Then there's of course the problem with the `switch` statement, or rather its cases. The character literal `'1'` is actually the same as the integer `49` in [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii). You should not use character literals here but integer literals, so change e.g. `'1'` to `1`.